# Can the fee produced by estimatefee be artificially manipulated?

Tags: transaction-fees

Could a miner who wanted more transaction fees manipulate the fee produced by estimatefee? If so, what percentage of hashpower would it take, and how long would you need it?

Comment: It's an estimator based on the assumed policy of recently mined blocks, that is, if a large miner has a policy that only takes transactions paying 1BTC per kilobyte then the estimation will naturally rise. I'm not what you would class as manipulation in that versus  `estimatefee` working as intended. Most wallets currently pay a flat fee per kilobyte, so I doubt much research has been done into it thus far anyway.

Comment: @Bitcoin What if the miner used his own money pay transaction fees, to pretend that there were more transactions paying 1 BTC than there really are?

Comment: I don't think that would have much effect but I'll look into it. You would have to be pretty determined to do that, if you attempted a sizable amount of "fake" fees in a block someone can just fork yours out and take the fees for themselves.

Answer (score -1):

No, estimatefee is calculated locally by bitcoind in function of some statistics done on mempool.

Comment: Ok, but those transactions are received from remote nodes, right?

Comment: ye, but not from a single node. A miner can't change your estimatefee behavior.

Comment: Miners can change your estimatefee behavior. For example, they can accept very low fee transactions.

Comment: In your question you are talking about "a miner", and the answer is no, a single miner cannot do this.